# When using JQuery Linkify plugin, how do I truncate the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hyperlink

https://github.com/maranomynet/linkify

I'm using this plugin.  It works, and everything's fine.  But is there an option I can plug into it so that if the url length is longer than "X", then truncate it, and add "..."?

Right now the URLs are so long.

I notice in the demo there is a "handleLinks" callback function, but how do I use that?

Comment: If you will cut the link then it will be useless as a link but if you want to display it like this then you can implement some other jQuery plugin to implement this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, you can use `handleLinks` callback function. For example I wrote simple functional that you need:

```
handleLinks: function (links) {
    for (var i = 0, cnt = links.length, tmpLink; i < cnt; i++) {
        tmpLink = links[i].innerHTML;
        if (tmpLink.length > 10) {
            links[i].innerHTML = tmpLink.substr(0, 10) + '...';
        }
    }
}
```

It truncates links if they longer than 10 characters. You can modify this script by your needs.

Comment: It might be unnecessary, but I'd be tempted to add `links[i].title = tmpLink;` just to be sure that there's a means by which the user can see the full URL (I know it's visible in the status bar at the bottom of the screen, but even so...).

Answer (score 3):

For URL truncating I choose to shorten in the middle, as the domain and file are usually more important than the directory path.

Taken and adapted for this question from my [GitHub fork](http://github.com/nadinengland/Sugar) of Andrew Plummer's JavaScript Library [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com).

```
String.prototype.shorten = function(length, position, countSplitter, splitter) {
  if (this.length < 1 && length < 1) return String(this);

  if (!(typeof(splitter) === 'string')) splitter = '...';
  if (!(typeof(countSplitter) === 'boolean')) countSplitter = true;

  var balance = (countSplitter) ? splitter.length : 0;

  if (length <= balance || this.length <= length) return String(this);

  // Perform shortening
  var shortened, beforeSplitter, afterSplitter;

  if (position == 'left') {
    afterSplitter = this.substring(this.length - length + balance, this.length - 1);
    shortened = splitter + afterSplitter;
  } else if (position == 'right') {
    beforeSplitter = this.substring(0, length - balance);
    shortened = beforeSplitter + splitter;
  } else {
    beforeSplitter = this.substring(0, Math.ceil((length / 2) - (balance / 2)));
    afterSplitter = this.substring(this.length - Math.floor((length / 2) - (balance / 2)), this.length);
    shortened = beforeSplitter + splitter + afterSplitter;
  }

  return shortened;
}
```

Example of shortening a Url so the resultant string is 20 characters long:

```
var toShorten = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156458/when-using-jquery-linkify-plugin-how-do-i-truncate-the-url';
var shortened = toShorten.shorten(20); // Output: 'http://st...-the-url'
```

*Note: this code has only been proof read and not unit tested. The [Sugar implementation](https://github.com/nadinengland/Sugar/blob/master/release/development/sugar-edge.development.js#L3593) has been [unit tested](https://github.com/nadinengland/Sugar/blob/master/unit_tests/environments/sugar/string.js#L1171), however.*